# Rails: Issues during after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, self-join, before-filter

I'm making a relatively complex crossword solver Rails app, but this problem only relates to two of its interacting models: Crossword and Cell.

**The Plan:**

Before a Crossword is created, I have it populate with a number of Cells equal to its (rows * columns). Then after all of the cells are populated for that puzzle, each cell is associated with the cells adjacent to it.

Here is the abridged version of the Cell class. Note that each cell has a reciprocal association with its neighboring cells, set up by the `.assign_bordering_cells` method.

```
class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base

  ....

  has_one :right_cell, class_name: 'Cell', foreign_key: 'left_cell_id', inverse_of: :left_cell
  has_one :below_cell, class_name: 'Cell', foreign_key: 'above_cell_id', inverse_of: :above_cell
  belongs_to :left_cell, class_name: 'Cell', foreign_key: 'left_cell_id', inverse_of: :right_cell
  belongs_to :above_cell, class_name: 'Cell', foreign_key: 'above_cell_id', inverse_of: :below_cell

  def assign_bordering_cells!
    puts "Assign bordering cells for cell in row #{self.row}, column #{self.col}"
    self.left_cell = self.crossword.cells.find_by_row_and_col(self.row, self.col-1) unless (self.col == 1)
    self.above_cell = self.crossword.cells.find_by_row_and_col(self.row-1, self.col) unless (self.row == 1)
    self.save
  end
end
```

And here is the abridged Crossword class. After it populates the cells, the `.link_cells` method iterates through all of those cells and *should* link them to their neighbors.

```
class Crossword < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :populate_cells
  after_create :link_cells

  ...

  def populate_cells
    row = 1
    while (row <= self.rows)
      col = 1
      while (col <= self.cols)
        self.cells << Cell.new(row: row, col: col, is_across_start: col == 1, is_down_start: row == 1)
        col += 1
      end
      row += 1
    end
  end

  def link_cells
    self.cells.each {|cell| cell.assign_bordering_cells! }
  end

end
```

The end result should be that each cell "knows" which cell is above, below, left and to the right of it. I've accounted for the edge cells that might be missing 1-2 of these adjacet cells.

**The Hitch:**

When I seed my database with a new Crossword, the Cells are created correctly for it. However, although `.link_cells` is definitely called and `.assign_bordering_cells!` triggers once for each cell, the Cell-Cell associations just don't get saved.

If I run Crossword.first.link_cells *after* I've seeded the database, all of the Cells link up perfectly. It's exactly the same process, but one is happening in the `:after_create` filter and one I'm typing into the Rails console.

**The Question:**
Why does `.link_cells` work in Rails console after I've created a Crossword, but not in my `:after_create` filter for Crossword objects?